# Alternative to vectors for large data sets? C++

Tags: c++, search

I am looking for a data structure that holds data in order that its inserted (like a vector) that needs to hold millions of unsigned longs. The key is that it needs to have a lookup thats better than O(logn), because it will get searched against a similar vector of the same size. Is there something that exists like this?

If I insert 10, 20, 30 and then iterate over the set, I need to guarantee the order of 10, 20, 30. My data is a string I converted into a unsigned long to reduce memory use, that is reverse decodable.

EDIT:
Since people are asking, I am comparing two vectors against each other (both very large in size) to get the difference.

Small Example:

```
vector 1: 10 20 30 40 50 60

vector 2: 11 24 30 40 55 70 90

result:   30 40
```

Comment: unordered_map  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Comment: Why isn't vector good enough?  When you say "it will get searched against a similar vector of the same size", what does that mean?

Comment: The obvious alternative that meets your requirements is `std::deque`, though since you haven't said what's wrong with `std::vector` for your purposes, it's impossible to guess whether `std::deque` will be better, worse, or similar. `std::list` will also hold items in sequence, but chances of its being an improvement are quite remote.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the problem with vector? A mere million (10^6) of unsigned longs is a very small amount of data.

Comment: ~100M unsigned lng lng's for each vector

Answer (score 4):

I never used it myself and it might be out-of-date compared to recent C++ version features (last update is from 2011), but [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) is meant to be a set of containers and algorithms built for very big amount of data.
It might fit your need.

> The core of STXXL is an implementation of the C++ standard template
>   library STL for external memory (out-of-core) computations, i. e.,
>   **STXXL implements containers and algorithms that can process huge
>   volumes of data that only fit on disks.** While the closeness to the STL
>   supports ease of use and compatibility with existing applications,
>   another design priority is high performance.
>
> The key features of STXXL are:
>
> - Transparent support of parallel disks. The library provides implementations of basic parallel disk algorithms. STXXL is the only
>     external memory algorithm library supporting parallel disks.
> - The library is able to handle problems of very large size (tested to up to dozens of terabytes).
> - Improved utilization of computer resources. STXXL implementations of external memory algorithms and data structures benefit from
>     overlapping of I/O and computation.
> - Small constant factors in I/O volume. A unique library feature called "pipelining" can save more than half the number of I/Os, by
>     streaming data between algorithmic components, instead of temporarily
>     storing them on disk. A development branch supports asynchronous
>     execution of the algorithmic components, enabling high-level task
>     parallelism.
> - Shorter development times due to well known STL-compatible interfaces for external memory algorithms and data structures.
> - STL algorithms can be directly applied to STXXL containers; moreover, the I/O complexity of the algorithms remains optimal in most
>     of the cases.
>
> For internal computation, parallel algorithms from the MCSTL or the
>   libstdc++ parallel mode are optionally utilized, making the algorithms
>   inherently benefit from multi-core parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

A hash map is one way you will have faster lookup than a sorted vector. You must have c++11 support to use it.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/
To preserve the order of the data the only way would be to maintain a vector beside it that stored the int's as well
Before you jump to using it you should consider how you are going to use this data structure (access pattern). Also consider what the data you will be getting is likely to be.
Here is boost's version of the same thing http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/unordered.html

Comment: Just wanted to throw a note in that you can get a hash map without C++11 by using Qt.

Comment: @CoryKlein post a link and I'll put it in the answer as well

Comment: A hash map is definitely not the only way to have faster lookup than a sorted vector.

Comment: Hash map doesn't store the data in the order it was inserted

Comment: Heres my question, will unordered map keep the values in order, so if I insert 10, 20, 30 and then run the iterator, will it guarantee the output as 10, 20, 30? Also with hashmap I need a key/val pair, but my data is a "hashvalue" of sorts, in the sense that its a string I converted into a unsigned long to reduce memory use that is reverse decodable.

Comment: No, you will probably not get that order

Comment: @DietrichEpp not in terms of big o, also give examples if you want to correct me

Comment: Sparse array, Patricia trie, Crit-bit tree -- all of these will have O(1) lookup since the key size is fixed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I changed the wording, but still those are data structures that the OP would either have to find a lib supporting them or write him self

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should use is unordered_map  combined with maybe a doubly-linked list for the order.

So every time you add a new item to your database you add it first to the front (or the end) of the linked list, and then add it to the hashmap where the key is the value (the unsigned int) and the "value" (from the key/value pair) is the pointer to the the object in the linked list.
So now if you want a fast lookup you look in the hashmap, and if you want to iterate by order you use the linked list.
Of course when you want to remove an object you have to remove them from both, but complexity wise it's the same (O(1) amortized for everything).

This will of course increase your memory by 2 or 3 compared to just using a hashmap.